# Removing space between bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project. I use bootstrap 3.0.0.

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="padding-top:5px;">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group input-group-sm pull-left">
            <button id="btnAllItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[0].id);" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 1}">all</button>
            <button id="btnNewItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[1].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 2}">new</button>
            <button id="btnUpdateItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[2].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 3}">update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="margin-bottom:1px!important">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:#ADD8E6">
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>SIM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here is a [feedler](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30999/) example of the code.

Here is how it looks in an image:

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, the search box has a small space from the left side and more space from right side.

My question is: how can I remove  the space from the left and right sides?

Answer (score 2):

You can have it stop align (float) right (remove the left space) by removing the `pull-right` from the `<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">`.

Do note that you will have to re-order your HTML entirely to still have it show on the right side of the screen (place the forms' HTML after the menu options).

You can remove the small `15px padding` on the right side by adding:

```
margin: 0 -15px;
```

to the `.input-group` CSS. (Negative padding does not exist, hence we use negative margin to counteract the padding).

Do note that the reason this padding exists is because the col-classes add this small gutter. This gutter is normally removed by a `<div class="row"></div>` surrounding it (which has a `margin: 0 -15px`), which would be best practise to implement here also; making your form HTML:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- we add this row -->
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </div>
           </input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Just utilize the bootstrap grid system properly and you can achieve it.

A bootstrap row contains 12 columns so use 4 columns for the button and rest 8 columns for the search box. Bootstrap columns should always be contained inside a row. so you have to create a row div. also give `col-xs-12` to your input-group class to make the search bar take the full width of 8 columns.

**working example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
<div style="padding-top:5px;">
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 pull-right" style="">
            <div class="col-xs-12 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="col-xs-12 form-control" placeholder="search">
                <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-left">
        <div class="btn-group">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <button id="btnAllItems btn-block" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[0].id);" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 1}">all</button>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <button id="btnNewItems btn-block" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[1].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 2}">new</button>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <button id="btnUpdateItems btn-block" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[2].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 3}">update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="margin-bottom:1px!important">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:#ADD8E6">
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>SIM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've placed the search box in a column, which has (1) a fixed sized, based on the number of columns you want, and (2) some padding. You need to not place it in said column class - you already do this for the buttons on the right, and then specify the width of the search box to whatever it needs to be.

For these sorts of layouts I recommend you use flexbox though, so you don't hardcode pixel or percentage values.

Answer (score 1):

The space from the **right** side exist because `col-md-5` class is adding a `padding: 0 15px;`.

This is usually solved by adding the `row` class which will *hidden* the `padding`. This is happening because `row` class is adding a `margin: 0 -15px;` (left and right).

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
    <!--Your content-->
   </div>
</div>
```

For the space from the **left** I think you want to move buttons closer to the search input. Create a element `<div class="input-group-btn">` before your input and move your buttons there.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <!-- add buttons here -->

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
            <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The snippet below shows how the space from the **right and left** is *removed* by adding `row` class to a parent `div` and using `input-group-btn`.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div style="padding-top:5px;">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 pull-right">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                 <button id="btnAllItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[0].id);" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 1}">all</button>
                             <button id="btnNewItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[1].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 2}">new</button>
            <button id="btnUpdateItems" ng-click="list.getItems(list.itemsStatus[2].id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-class = "{'active' : list.currentItemsStatus.id === 3}">update</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                <div class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="margin-bottom:1px!important">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background:#ADD8E6">
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>SIM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```